# Check Twitter Streaming Access Level

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a twitter account with elevated access levels (15% of firehose and extra keywords) but I have been having some issues with tokens. I am trying to resolve them now, but can't figure out if the elevated rate limit is being used.

Is there a good way to test that I am receiving this amount? Or even a place to login and check? Logging into [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com) site doesn't seem to give any information about access level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a filter stream with more than 400 keywords.
If you can, then your account is perfectly fine.

By the way, do you mind if I ask you how did you have that elevated access levels account. My application really needs this kind of account to track more than 400 keywords but I have no idea how to get it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I was hoping to have an API call or programmatic check. Our company had whitelisted accounts from the early days of Twitter which grandfathered us into getting elevated access. Otherwise I can't really help. Try contacting the Twitter Dev relation guy @episod on Twitter